# Invert horizontal AngularJS Slider Custom Scale

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, slider, angularjs-slider

I'm using this [AngularJS Slider](https://github.com/angular-slider/angularjs-slider), the horizontal one. 
I took the example that has the points divided by a different distance. That example, started from a wide distance, to end with a small distance:
[image]

What I wanted to do, is to invert the scale keeping the numbering.
This is my code: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/go8bxcwo/1/)

As you can see, I changed the function `customValueToPosition`:

```
customValueToPosition: function(val, minVal, maxVal) {
  val = Math.sqrt(val);
  minVal = Math.sqrt(minVal);
  maxVal = Math.sqrt(maxVal);
  var range = minVal - maxVal;
  return (val - maxVal) / range;      
}
```

There are two problems: The numbers are inverted. I would like to leave from 0 instead of starting 5.
Then there is a problem with the click of the first and the last value. If you click slightly before the first element (or just after the last item), the selection falls on the opposite value. So, if I just click just before the first element first, select the last one. And viceversa.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**:I think this is what you are looking for. The old one was x^2 scale so in order to make it looks like this we need to change both functions and in   customPositionToValue return square root instead of power of 2, and in  customValueToPosition we need to use power of 2 to calculate range and return procentage that describes position of the point.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $timeout, $modal) {
        $scope.minSlider = {
            value: 2
        };
        $scope.slider = {
            options: {
            floor: 0,
            ceil: 5,
            step: 1,
            showTicksValues: true,
            customValueToPosition: function(val, minVal, maxVal) {
                val = Math.pow(val,2)
                maxVal = Math.pow(maxVal, 2)
                minVal = Math.pow(minVal, 2)
                var range = maxVal - minVal
                return (val - minVal) / range
            },
            customPositionToValue: function(percent, minVal, maxVal) {
                minVal = Math.pow(minVal,2);
                maxVal = Math.pow(maxVal,2);
                var value = percent * (maxVal - minVal) + minVal;
                return Math.sqrt(value)
            }
            }
        };
});
```

Hope it helps.

[image]

Here is working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/VfMkWLoMIGUSmsqYGpye?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Numbering is fine now, but not the scale. In fact, the first points must be small, and the more it increases (then going to the right, to 5) increases the space between dots

Comment: Sorry for didn't understand you. I will try to edit my answer soon.